# How to manage notification manager null?

Tags: android, json, push-notification

When I sent notification that time notification manager show is null, how i handle this?

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String message, String msgTitle) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
            String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(Config.CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

Here notification manager get null.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
Uri defaultSoundUri = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Config.CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_4)
    .setContentTitle(msgTitle)
    .setContentText(message)
    .setChannelId(Config.CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .addAction(R.drawable.folder, "OPEN", pendingIntent);
Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).notify(getRequestCode(), 
notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code it works for you :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 
 PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

 NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cum_small_icon)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);


    builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND | NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    createNotificationChannel();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(code, builder.build());
```

> **createNotificationChannel()**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

Comment: notificationManagerCompat.notify(code, builder.build()); 
what is code??

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize `notificationManager` like this:

```
 notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```